# What does "System program detected error" mean and how serious is it?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, vmware-player

I am running ubuntu 32-bit using VMware player on windows 7 64-bit. I logged in to my ubuntu account and did my normal activities (check for updates, browse askubuntu, etc.) but when I checked for updates it said it had errors authenticating because of which I restarted and downloaded Chromium browser, opened it and synced my apps. But when the extensions synced the launcher (unity) crashed, so I sent the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> signal which didn't work. I opened dash and typed 'Shut down' and my host crashed and I hard-rebooted.

The computer restarted a few times and when I logged on to my ubuntu account I was welcomed the following screen:

[image]

The mouse did not seem to work so I right clicked the buttons and pressed enter.
When I reported the second one I received an internal error. So I signed out and signed back in. Everything worked fine from then.

How do I verify everything is alright?

I'm running directly from the ISO rather than burning it.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you emulating ? Can you provide more information on the error ? A log ?

Comment: @MrVaykadji I am running Ubuntu version 14.04. I do not have access to a log.

Comment: @Jobin Nice edit. :0

Comment: Look... I'm almost ready to stop using Ubuntu (well not really, but I want to make a point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If the virtual machine is really important:

If the ubuntu virtual machine you installed is really important, i.e. contains data that you cannot afford to lose and have invested a lot time and effort installing applications and configuring them:

1. Clone the virtual machine first: This is pretty easy; you can just copy all the files of the virtual machine present on the host (Windows 7 here) to a persistent and reliable location(an external disk, may be) and ensure that you don't damage it further.
2. Check the system logs and logs of the application that you feel might have caused the problem: This is tedious and time consuming; the system logs are present in `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/dmesg.0`, etc. and most of the application logs in `/var/log` directory. Read and analyze them to get messages such as "error" or "critical", etc. Usually, the more important (critical) ones are in red such as this:

   [image: critical error]

   and analyze as to what caused the crash and resolve it, if possible.

### If the virtual machine is not pretty important:

**Report and ignore.** This message might be just an application crash report, but is essential that the developers know about it (which is why it is encouraged to report and should be done so). You can continue working unless something really bizarre happens(the crash might now be the cause in future) or create a new virtual machine right away.

However, it would be great if you could reproduce the crash and report it as a bug to the developers of the concerned package so that it is resolved upstream and other users (or you) in future are not affected by the same.

Comment: Concerned package? It's an internal error!